# Typescript: error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'string | number' and 'string | number'

Tags: typescript

I have a function bellow:

```
function testFunc<T extends string[]|number[]>(a: T) {
   return a[0] + a[1];
}
```

And when I compile it, it get an error:

```
error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'string | number' and 'string | number'.

    return a[0]+a[1];
            ~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

I can't understand why I get that error because `T extends string[] | number[]`  not `T extends (string | number)[]`. T only gets string[] or number[] but the error show  `Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'string | number' and 'string | number'` ?

Comment: if you want to return just string, can simply just `return \`${a[0]}${a[1]}\``

Answer (score 0):

Typescript's type checker generally does not prove every provable property about your code. In this case, the expression `a[0]` has type `string | number` because it either comes from an array of strings or an array of numbers; likewise `a[1]` has the type `string | number`.

Importantly, Typescript does not keep track of the fact that both of those `string | number` types came from the same array; it only tracks the type of each variable, not how the type of one variable might depend on the type of another.

So Typescript sees this as a `(string | number) + (string | number)`, which is a type error. A human might see it as more like `(string + string) | (number + number)`, but such a thing cannot be represented in Typescript's type-checking algorithm.

---

But actually, Typescript is no less right to warn you about this code than it is right to warn in the case where `a[0]` and `a[1]` might have different types:

```js
function add(a: (string | number)[]): string | number {
    return a[0] + a[1]; // type error
}
```

In Javascript there is no problem with this, and it is easy to deduce that the return type is satisfied because if you add strings and/or numbers, the result will be either a string or a number. So this code is type-safe; but Typescript reports a type error anyway. The reason is because it's rare that anyone *intended* to write code that sometimes does arithmetic and other times does string concatenation. So the type error is to warn you about a probable mistake, not to warn you that the code isn't type-safe.

Your code, likewise, sometimes does arithmetic and other times does string concatenation; it never converts a number to a string in order to do string concatenation, but it's still rare that you would want code that can have both behaviours. So the same probable mistake is being warned about in the `string[] | number[]` case as it is in the `(string | number)[]` case.

Comment: I have one more question:  

`function testFunc<T extends string|number>(a: T[]) {  
   if (typeof a[0] == "number" && typeof a[1] == "number")  
    return a[0] + a[1];  
   else return "nothing"  
}`  

when I put brackets in T[], it change the error:   
`Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'.`  

I have added type guard but it still doesn't work. Please help me :(

Comment: Control-flow type narrowing doesn't work on array components like that; try writing `let x = a[0], y = a[1];` at the start of the function, then using `x` and `y` instead.